# ng-grid external filter \ filter by date range

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, ng-grid

I've created a nice table with ng-grid.
Now I'm stuck.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to filter ng-grid rows by date range?

   (I'm using datepicker \ daterangepicker to get the dates)
2. Is there a way to use both external and internal filter in ng-grid?